# Creating a for loop for each column in a tibble r

Tags: r, for-loop, outliers

I know that creating for loops in r is inadvisable, but in this case I don't think I have a choice.

I am trying to get rid of outliers for my data set, and have come up with a way to do that separately for each of the columns.

Here is the data:

```
# A tibble: 91 x 4
   F_Total A_Total S_Total Category_Total
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
 1      14      11      18             23
 2      13      18      18             28
 3      NA      15      16             27
 4      17      14      19             21
 5      12       8      13             27
 6      20      15      24             25
 7      16      12      11             15
 8      14      15      18             21
 9      16      16      21             29
10      13      16      13             23
# … with 81 more rows
```

and here is the way I want to calculate outliers:

```
PND_outliers <- PND_small %>% 
  mutate(upper_limit = mean(F_Total,na.rm=TRUE) + 2.5*sd(F_Total,na.rm=TRUE),
         lower_limit = mean(F_Total,na.rm=TRUE) - 2.5*sd(F_Total,na.rm=TRUE),
         CleanF_Total = ifelse(F_Total > upper_limit | F_Total < lower_limit, NA, F_Total))
```

Now, I could write the above code three more times and create "clean" columns for each of them manually, but I'm wondering if there is a way for me to create a loop to do it for me? For example if I was using Python, I would create a for loop that will say for each of the columns calculate the limit then create a new column based on that. Is there a way to do this in R?

Thanks! (sorry if this is a basic stupid question, I'm still trying to get my bearings in R)
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dplyr`s `across`-function and choose the columns you want to mutate:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(ends_with("Total"), ~ ifelse(.x > mean(.x,na.rm=TRUE) + 2.5*sd(.x,na.rm=TRUE) |
                                             .x < mean(.x,na.rm=TRUE) - 2.5*sd(.x,na.rm=TRUE),
                                             NA, .x)))
```

I used `ends_with("Total")` to choose the columns. Depending on your data, you could use `everything()`, `starts_with()`, `matches()` to get the desired columns.